# Adding a div box / with Button under Featured Image in posts

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've managed to add a '*featured image*' that floats to the left that populates each post excerpt on my Wordpress website's homepage. Similar to how it comes in on this website: http://tinyurl.com/y8tk6oq ***BUT***! I'm trying to add a div / button to appear under it, taking the width of my image, with just a tiny bit of padding. I'd love to add within this working code so that it appears at all my posts the same, and I'd work with each individually to add the corresponding separate links.

**I've made several attempts at duplicating what's working below but with a DIV, repositioned underneath, but still no such luck.**

```
 <?php if($image= get_post_meta($post->ID, "image", true)) { ?>
                        <div class="postImage">
                        <img class="postImg" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" /> 
                        </div>                    
                    <?php } else if($isbn= get_post_meta($post->ID, "isbn", true)) { ?>
                        <div class="postImage">


                        <img class="postImg" src="http://www.randomhouse.com/images/dyn/cover/?source=<?php echo $isbn; ?>&height=225&maxwidth=150" />

                        </div>

                <?php } else { print"<div>";}?>
```

Comment: Will the button link to the Post, or do you want each to link to a different custom URL?

Comment: Yes. A different custom URL unfortunately. But I'd like to think about that a little later, I was thinking about just floating a text link over. BUT, at this point I'd just like to get the div to populate underneath each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add a button, you can just add an anchor in the loop.  I've added a button with a class of `readmore` which you can then apply CSS rules to.

```
 <?php if($image= get_post_meta($post->ID, "image", true)) { ?>
                    <div class="postImage">
                    <img class="postImg" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" /> 
                    </div>                    
                <?php } else if($isbn= get_post_meta($post->ID, "isbn", true)) { ?>
                    <div class="postImage">


                    <img class="postImg" src="http://www.randomhouse.com/images/dyn/cover/?source=<?php echo $isbn; ?>&height=225&maxwidth=150" />
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmore">Read More</a>
                    </div>

            <?php } else { print"<div>";}?>
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to link to the permalink of the post, and instead want to link to an external URL of your choosing on a post-by-post basis, you can accomplish that by using custom fields.  Check out [this article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-link-to-external-links-from-the-post-title-in-wordpress/) for a how to.

Comment: I've just tried your code, and that's what I initially thought as well. BUTTTT! It didn't work, just tried styling as: .readmore {

background-color: #333;
width: 225px;
height; 50px;

}

Comment: And nothing displayed underneath.

Comment: Does the link appear in the rendered HTML source?

Comment: Note, I edited my original answer and added information about linking to a custom URL as opposed to the Permalink.

Comment: I've tried to style again with styles commented above, and still no div appearing with your suggested code as answer. I'm hitting the same wall as with my attempts...